# UIMA RUTA - Annotation

Tags: uima, ruta

I need to declare several annotation types. To do this I've added dictionaries to "resources" folder. Each dictionary contains a list of utterances and meanings, ex. (Actions.csv):

1. cancel;CANCEL;
2. cancellation;CANCEL;
3. canceled;CANCEL;
4. delete;CANCEL;
5. stop;CANCEL;
6. close;CANCEL;
7. terminate;CANCEL;
8. termination;CANCEL;

When I run my code - nothing happens, neither annotation types declared, nor results in .xmi file.
Can you please help me, and explain where is my problem?
Thank you in advance

Here is my code:

```
PACKAGE com.omilia.entertask;

DECLARE WORD;
W{->MARK(WORD)};

DECLARE CARD;
W{REGEXP("card")->MARK(CARD)};

INT count_words;
Document {TOTALCOUNT (WORD,1,10,count_words)};

// Dictionaries

WORDTABLE Actions ='Actions.csv';
DECLARE Annotation Action (STRING meaning);
Document {-> MARKTABLE (Action, 1, Actions, "meaning" = 2)};
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your latest (and used) main.ruta file. I think that the used file is not the same as the one you have used in this post, because the screenshot recognize Entities that are not in the script (and there is also a mismatch in the package naming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your Ruta script in the Eclipse workbench. I simple create a new Ruta project and put the files on the correct location (example.ruta, Action.csv and input.txt). I didn't create or modify any other files.
After that I select the example.ruta file and choose "Run as -> UIMA Ruta". The input.txt.xmi file is correctly generated and marked the correct annotations.

So you script seems to be ok. Are all the files on the correct location? Don't you see any errors/exceptions?

[image]

Comment: I have double checked my Project - there were two .xmi files (one in input, second in output), it works but to word underlined